# How long do upgrades last for?

Tags: tankball-2

The length of the power ups seem to vary, I assume they're based on time, but I don't know how long. Although they could be based on shots fired or be cancelled after being hit.

How long do the power ups last for?

Comment: I *think* the speed upgrade is based on time, because it seems to me that if you die after getting one, you'll respawn with it still active for the remainder of its duration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The **weapon upgrades** last for 10-shots, it's not time based. If you pick-up another weapon upgrade while under the affect of another one your counter resets to 10. The affects won't stack.